# How can I create the migration and seed files for CircleCI with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, continuous-integration, circleci

We are looking to implement Continuous Integration using Circle CI but we are not sure on how should we proceed with our test database. We have the following alternatives in mind:

1. Run the migrations from scratch (the problem is that we have a lot of migration files, our first migrations were moving everything from MySQL and PostgreSQL and using a legacy database, so, it's rather complex).
2. Recreate the current DB and have a .sql file that will create our current tables, and then, we create a seeder to fill the information that we need.

But we are not sure which is the best alternative or if we're missing something?

Thank you

Comment: I'd go for option 2...and then set up log shipping on your main mysql database.

Comment: Migrations provide value in that they allow multiple environments to keep up to date with the database state required for the application at that time. However, when your application matures you do not *need* to keep a full migration history, you can, for example, coordinate with all developers to replace your historic migrations with a single consolidated migration that creates the *current* schema. This requires some coordination (i.e you ensure each database (developers, staging, qa) is up to date with the schema) but it's very helpful if you find yourself with hundreds of migrations.

Comment: Perfect, I'll work with my team on the second option and in this way, start our CI. Thanks